# HTTP Content-Location for setting base URL

Tags: http

According to [W3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), **14.14 Content-Location** includes:

> Content-Location also defines the base URI for the entity

I'm trying to do:

- `/foo/123` is a URL for a document which can be served as JSON or HTML
- I want to serve the HTML requests such that the HTML-linked resources(images, css, ect) subsequently required use a base URL other than `/foo`

However, browsers not respecting this. Is there a way to do this outside `<base>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at an outdated spec (which by the way is an IETF spec, not a W3C spec). Please see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#header.content-location